# Unknown Error in Microsoft graph API Calendar module

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, http-error, microsoft-graph-calendar, python-daemon

As I'm trying to get my calendar with graph UI or with my daemon app, I get the same unknown error with the http error 404

For my app I got the needed permission **Calendars.Read** by the admin and added the proper scope. The app works nice, when I run simple query **https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/id**, I got the required profile, however as I run **/users/id/calendars**, it fails as shown above.

The same thing occurs as I just run **/me/calendars** in MS Graph UI as a ordinary user with only delegated rights.

Any ideas, what I'm missing?